# RestKit entity mapping for UnitTests does not work

Tags: unit-testing, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to create my RKEntityMapping outside of my UnitTest. The problem I have is it only works if I create it inside my test. For example, this works:

```
RKEntityMapping *accountListMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"CustomerListResponse"                                                            inManagedObjectStore:_sut.managedObjectStore];
[accountListMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"count":  @"pageCount",
                                                         @"page":   @"currentPage",
                                                         @"pages":  @"pages"}];
```

While the following does now work. The all to accoutListMapping returns exactly what is shown above using the same managed object store:
    RKEntityMapping *accountListMapping = [_sut accountListMapping];

When the `RKEntityMapping` is created in `_sut` I get this error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: -[SBAccountTests testAccountListFetch] : 0x9e9cd10: failed with error:
Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1007 "Cannot perform a mapping operation
with a nil destination object." UserInfo=0x8c64490 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot perform
a mapping operation with a nil destination object.}
```

I'm assuming the `nil` destination object it is referring to is `destinationObject:nil`.

```
RKMappingTest *maptest = [RKMappingTest testForMapping:accountListMapping
                                          sourceObject:_parsedJSON
                                     destinationObject:nil];
```

Comment: Yes, so provide a destination object.

Comment: If I create the mapping in-line with my test it works if I supply the destination object or not; RestKit docs don't provide one. If I create the mapping in a different class and pass it in as a return value then it does not work even if I pass in a destination object; it can't find any mappable values. I think this is a bug in RK.

Comment: Did you try debugging through your 2 cases? You may be better served asking on the RestKit google group or github wiki.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the destinationObject parameter. The error message is a bit confusing but it refers to the fact that the destination object could not be created. I have no idea why this is like this but I've debugged this and submitted an issue: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1756

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a category on the Mapped object for example

```
RestKitMappings+SomeClass

+ (RKObjectMapping*)responsemappings {
return mappings;
}
```

now this category has to be included in the test target as well otherwise the mapping will not be passed.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the file you have created has a target membership of both your main target, and your test target. You can find this by:

- clicking on the .m file of your class
- open the utilities toolbar (the one on the right)
- in the target membership section tick both targets.

This is because if your class does not have target membership to your test target, the test target actually creates a copy of the class that you have created, meaning it has a different binary file to the main target. This leads to that class using the test's version of the RestKit binary, rather than the main projects RestKit. This will lead to the isKindOfClass method failing when it tries to see if the mapping you have passed is of type RKObjectMapping from the main project, because it is of type RKObjectMapping from the test projects version of RestKit, so your mapping doesn't get used, and you get your crash.

At least this is my understanding of how the LLVM compiler works. I'm new to iOS dev so please feel free to correct if I got something wrong.

Comment: This is *exactly* what was happening to me. I can confirm this fix works. After adding all my .m files to the target, I also had to manually add my prefix header in build settings. Then everything worked great. Excellent find!

Answer (score 1):

This problem may also be caused by duplicated class definitions, when including RestKit components for multiple targets individually when using Cocoapods.

For more information on this have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860482/restkit-cocoapods-mapping-operation-failed-did-not-find-any-mappable-values).

Answer (score 0):

When you're running a test you aren't using the entire mapping infrastructure, so RestKit isn't going to create a destination object for you. It's only going to test the mapping itself. So you need to provide all three pieces of information to the test method or it can't work.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would matter in my case. The mapping works if I create it in the unit test class, but not if I create exact same mapping outside of the unit test class and pass it in as a return value. To unit test I don't want to copy-and-paste all my mapping into the unit test; too much code duplication. Also, this technique works for object mapping but not for entity mapping.