# RestKit & Cocoapods: Mapping operation failed / did not find any mappable values

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, cocoapods

When executing unit tests for RestKit Mapping Code with `RKMappingTest`s, they fail with exceptions such as:

`Mapping operation failed: Given nil destination object and unable to instantiate a destination object for mapping.`

or (when a destination object is passed into the `RKMappingTest`):

`Mapping operation did not find any mappable values for the attribute and relationship mappings in the given object representation`

---

RestKit is installed through Cocoapods using the following Podfile:

```
target :MyTarget do
    pod 'RestKit'
end

target :MyTargetTests do
    pod 'RestKit/Testing'
    pod 'RestKit/Search'
end
```

---

The RKMapping to be tested is created inside the regular application bundle and turns out properly when using the `po` command of the lldb debugger.

When the method for generating the RKEntityMapping is copy-pasted into the unit test class and executed there, everything is working properly.

---

#### Note:

Though I did answer my own question in the hope that it would be useful for somebody else with the same problem, I encourage anybody who can come up with a better solution to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reason why this happens:

> <sub>Disclaimer:</sub>
> <sup><sub>I am no expert on static libraries, linking and related dependencies. If I got something wrong about the way that linking or Cocoapods work, please correct me.</sub></sup>

For this `Podfile`, Cocoapods builds two static libraries – one for each target.

When the project is compiled, all the code in `MyTarget` will get linked against the `LibPods-MyTarget.a` library and all the code in `MyTargetTests` will get linked against the `LibPods-MyTargetTests.a` library.
Both of them contain a copy of the `RestKit/ObjectMapping` component (since it is a dependency of both `RestKit` and `RestKit/Testing`).

When generating a `RKMapping` in the application source (MyTarget), the class implementation from `LibPods-MyTarget.a` is used.
When using that mapping inside the unit test class, the RestKit implementation is linked from the other library.

Theoretically, both implementations contain the same source code, both classes have the same name, the same class number and probably even the underlying `objc_class` structs contain the same content.

When you call a method on it from the test class, it will execute as it should (with implementation coming from the apps library).
Saying: depending on where the object was alloc-inited, equal source code will be loaded from a different copy at a different memory location.

However, since the Objective-C `Class` construct is higher level than the underlying `objc_class` struct, they are not both the same.

---

**Example of what this means:**

Let's assume we have have a class called `MyObject`, that includes a method with the following signature:

```
+ (RKObjectMapping*)generateMapping;
```

While the method itself works perfectly fine, this test would fail:

```
- (void)testClassEquality {
    RKEntityMapping *mappingFromAppBundle = [MyObject generateMapping];
    Class testBundleMappingClass = [RKMapping class];
    
    XCTAssert([mappingFromAppBundle isMemberOfClass:testBundleMappingClass],
              @"Mapping class from app bundle doesn't match Mapping class from test bundle");
}
```

Because:

`[RKMapping class]` from `LibPods-MyTarget.a`
!=
`[RKMapping class]` from `LibPods-MyTargetTests.a`

---

RestKit heavily relies on `isMemberOfClass:` and `isSubclassOf:` operations for implementing its functionality. Therefore this kind of duplicate implementation breaks it.

---

## Solutions:

### Quick and dirty:

Don't use two different Cocoapod configurations for the two targets. Use a simple Podfile such as:

```
pod 'RestKit'    
pod 'RestKit/Testing'
pod 'RestKit/Search'
```

Then use the same library/configuration for both targets. The linker link against the same copy for both targets.

Dead-code-stripping should prevent the unneeded code from being included in your final application.

However: It will still need to be compiled on each build and if you have the `-ObjC` or `-all_load` linker flags set, the unused code will be shipping with your app.

### Even dirtier:

> I strongly advise against this, since it pretty much defeats the purpose of a unit test. I've seen this as another workaround and included it for the sake of completion:

Copy and paste the implementation of the code into the unit test class and use it from there.

### Suggestion:

Cocoapods makes a static library for every single component first and combines them into a bigger library for each target, project or workspace.

It should be possible, to link the small libraries directly into the target without using the big union. By doing this, without automation, one would however kill the automatic dependency management, that Cocoapods was built for.

If anybody has some time on their hands and implements a script for this or modifies Cocoapods to add functionality, please let me know.

---

### Other solutions?

If I'm missing a functionality that Cocoapods already has or you know any additional solutions, please comment or post it as another answer.

Comment: I had the same issue, but when I try the quick and dirty solution I get duplicate warnings on the RK classes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you found any solution on this?

Comment: @Tim Bodeit, how did you proceed to use the same configuration?

Comment: Usually it will be set by `pod install` automatically. But to make sure: Go to your project settings in the info tab under configurations -> Based on Configuration File.